# Can I overclock hardware on my HP 4545s Probook (there are no options for it in the BIOS)?

Tags: bios, overclocking

I have searched in vain for some way to overclock the hardware on my laptop.

The BIOS is unlike any BIOS I've seen before. It's a mouse-using GUI instead of the classic arrow-key blue screen funny font menus. Also unlike others, the Esc key is used to access it, instead of Del.

[image: My gay HP GUI BIOS]

I have searched in vain through every single option, and found zero options for CPU bus frequency adjustments, multiplier adjustments, RAM frequency etc. Nada.

Can I change the BIOS on my laptop to allow hardware adjustments for overclocking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Nearly all business-grade laptops (if not all laptops) are not intended for overclocking. Part of the reason for this is because after-market cooling is virtually impossible.

Also, nearly all of the BIOS of business-grade laptops (at least Probooks, ThinkPads, Precisions, and Latitudes) are like that. They only have the most basic settings that are required and useful in a corporate environment.